# javascript and currying

Tags: javascript, closures, anonymous-function, currying, partial-application

I am reading through John Resig's Secrets of Javascript ninja and was trying out one of the examples on currying and parital functions.   The code is as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
<button id="test">Click Me!</button>
</body>


<script type="text/javascript">
    Function.prototype.curry = function() {
        var fn = this,
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

       return function() {
           return fn.apply(this, args.concat(
               Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
           }; 
       };


    var elem = document.getElementById("test"); 
    var bindClick = elem.addEventListener.curry("click");
    bindClick(function(){   console.log("OK"); });
</script>
</html>
```

However, the following code seems to generate an error Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation on the apply function.

I cant seem to figure out the reason as it all seems to make sense. 
`bindClick` will return an anonymous function that calls the function `elem.addEventListener` with `window` as the function context (`this`) and the arguments will be `["click", function() {console.log("OK"); }]`

Comment: Actually, [this is not currying/schönfinkeling but partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application)

Comment: hmm. I read up a bit on the difference.. But am still a bit confused. Partial Application returns a function which acts like the function you pass in but which takes fewer arguments, the others having been "bound in". So, this is indeed partial application. However I don't understand why is it not currying?  It seems like John Resig in "Secrets of JS Ninja" and Douglas Crawford in "JS: The Good parts" define the same function and named it "curry"..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you've lost the context of the element. The `addEventListener` method has to be called on an element, but you're calling it on a function:

```
// Here, `this` refers to a function, not an element
return fn.apply(this, args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
```

You would need to pass in the element to your new function. For example:

```
Function.prototype.curry = function () {
    var fn = this,
    args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

     return function (context) {
         return fn.apply(
             context,
             args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1))
         );
     }; 
};
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/dbA4A/). Notice the addition of a `context` argument to the returned function, and also notice the addition of the second argument to the `slice` call - that's needed to remove the new `context` argument and only apply any following arguments.

Comment: Oh okie. Thanks.. :) Just a clarification though, you mentioned that the `this` refers to a function. I guess that is because it is invoked by the fn method?  Thus, in this cause, since fn refers to the addEventListener function, `this` would refer to the addEventListener method even though the anonymous function's `this` (invoked by bindClick() function)  refers to the `window` object?

Comment: @henrybai - Correct. But you need `this` to refer to an element, otherwise `addEventListener` won't have anything to actually apply to.

Comment: @henrybai: Yes, in `curry` the `this` refers to the addEventListener function - and is assigned to `fn` because we won't be able to use `this` in the anonymous function any more.

Btw, it would be easier to use `bind`: `var bindClick = elem.addEventListener.bind(elem, "click");`

Comment: @JamesAllardice @Bergi It seems like the `this` does refer window object as I did in my experiment here. Am I doing something wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/ya2hM/